# how to create a django form dropdown based on model records

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have tried to create a form based on model records like this:

```
class ActivityForm(forms.Form):
    acts = Activity.objects.all()
    for a in acts:
        print a
    activities = forms.ChoiceField(choices=acts)
```

When I try to present this in the template, I get the error:

```
'Activity' object is not iterable
```

How can I create a form with a dropdowns based on the Activity model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be this:   `activities = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=acts)`